# how can i perform some action on click of two buttons simultaneously

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId()== R.id.but1 && v.getId()== R.id.but2)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that you want them to be clicked togather?

Comment: silly baby .... what is ur concept you want to clicked together or take action  after clicking two buttons

Comment: Question is unclear. You need a "two finger action"?

Comment: he want the two buttons to be clicked simultaneously. I think that what he meant.

Comment: means he got two mouse pointer?

Comment: yes i want two finger action that is two buttons to be clicked simultaneously . Below given answer is working but its not that i wanted . there is no such event or method through which i can perform such action ie Both buttons has to be clicked to perform next activity

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such event that can be associated to two controls. event handlers only associated to one control and that is different than assigning the same listener to two button. listener will receive a call from every button separately.

Also, listeners will never be triggered together because both run in the same thread (The UI thread). It's impossible to catch on click event for both controls at some moment. one listener will be triggered and then the other. Even if we assumed that the user managed to click those together at the same millisecond or so in the perfect world. Any way who can decide that when they are clicked at same millisecond they considered to be clicked to gather! why not same nanosecond. and why not the same hour :)

Ok, it's enough explaining the click event.

What we need is the touch event and it can be played as follow (the code will also explain how the touch event work):

Activity Class Members:

```
public boolean b1Down = false, b2Down = false;
```

onCreate Method Code:

```
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean consume = false;
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    b1Down = false;
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    b1Down = true;

                    if (b2Down)
                    {
                        // both are clicked now //
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Both are clicked now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    consume = true;
                }

                return consume;
            }
        });

        b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean consume = false;
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    b2Down = false;
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    b2Down = true;

                    if (b1Down)
                    {
                        // both are clicked now //
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Both are clicked now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    consume = true;
                }

                return consume;
            }
        });
```